# R superheat package heatmaps: change bottom axis labels font size

Tags: r, heatmap

I want to increase the bottom axis labels size of a heatmap created by the `superheat` package in R.

According to the [vignette](https://rlbarter.github.io/superheat/index.html), this could be done via the `bottom.label.size` parameter. However, this doesn't change the font size for me (see RSession below), but only changes the margin of the box in which the label is written:

```
library(dplyr)
library(superheat)

matrix(1:9, ncol = 3) %>% superheat(bottom.label.size = 0.1)
```

[image: superheat with bottom label size 0.1]

```
matrix(1:9, ncol = 3) %>% superheat(bottom.label.size = 0.05)
```

[image: superheat with bottom label size 0.05]

Does anyone know how to control this? Is this a bug or am I missing something?

RSession info:

```
R version 3.3.2 (2016-10-31)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 7 x64 (build 7601) Service Pack 1

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United States.1252  LC_CTYPE=English_United States.1252    LC_MONETARY=English_United States.1252
[4] LC_NUMERIC=C                           LC_TIME=English_United States.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] superheat_0.1.0 dplyr_0.5.0    

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] Rcpp_0.12.8      digest_0.6.11    assertthat_0.1   grid_3.3.2       R6_2.2.0         plyr_1.8.4      
 [7] gtable_0.2.0     DBI_0.5-1        magrittr_1.5     scales_0.4.1     ggplot2_2.2.1    lazyeval_0.2.0  
[13] labeling_0.3     tools_3.3.2      munsell_0.4.3    colorspace_1.3-2 tibble_1.2
```

Comment: https://rlbarter.github.io/superheat/legend.html#size-3 read about legend size. `bottom.label.size` changes bottom label which in your case is 1 2 3

Comment: I do not wish to change the legend size. And I am aware of `bottom.label.size` and have demonstrated how it does not work in this simple example.

Comment: You are right, I misread your question. How about `bottom.label.text.size` parameter?

Comment: Works, thank you. Wonder why it is not mentioned.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
matrix(1:9, ncol = 3) %>% superheat(bottom.label.size = 0.1, bottom.label.text.size = 10)
```

[image]